# svn/git/mercurial mirror

Tags: svn, git, mercurial

I'm looking for a simple solution to mirror different repository to a single svn server.

My problem is the following:

I have many dependencies in my projects, some are hosted on Google code, some in my personnal svn server, some on github and some other on mercurial servers.

Having many different source system is problematic when dealing with dependencies, PIP makes it easier but the solution isn't perfect.

The other part of the problem is availability. Sometimes I make a svn up or try to checkout a project and it fails because Google Code is down for maintenance and I get a bad gateway error.

Having a svn to mirror all those project would resolve both of my problem. But I never heard of such solution. Does it exists ?

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct experience in this area, but I found a couple of links that should prove helpful.

First, an [article](http://www.codeography.com/2010/03/17/howto-mirror-git-to-subversion.html) on mirroring git to subversion. Fairly straightforward, with how to proceed depending on if your original source is in git or subversion.

As for Mercurial, I found this [article](http://blog.experimentalworks.net/2009/12/writing-a-hg-to-subversion-gate/) discussing the whole DVCS<->Subversion synchronization issue. It's more for teams, but the gist of it seems valid for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out github too - you can import a project from SVN using github and do it online on their servers (as long as it's a public project it's free). This isn't mirroring and you have to use git not SVN but maybe worth checking out..